# On verbal parentheses

Tags: grammar, usage

I know that one of the peculiarities of the German language is this thing called *verbal parentheses*, which extends all the way from the auxiliary verb to the unonjugated form of the verb.

What I would actually like to know, though, is whether these verbal parentheses do have a maximum length. In other words, when do they stop being practical because of their length, and when do the extra words, which might have been part of them if it hadn't been for merely practical reasons of legibility, start being relocated to other sentences?

Does such a length limit on verbal parentheses exist at all in the language?

Comment: That is like asking whether there is a limit to large numbers that presents any sum from going to infinity :) Nor is there such a "legal limit" in language when it comes to sentence length. Or perhaps you are asking this because you encountered a German sentence or subclause that you felt was "too long"?

Comment: @Eugene Seidel I never asked about a "legal limit". I merely asked whether verbal parentheses have a practical limit: "practical reasons of legibility". There may be no limit whatsoever on the length of these things, but there surely must be a practical one, based entirely on how hard to read such a sentence might get beyond a certain point. This is my real question.

Comment: O.K., so perhaps empirical studies of how comprehension of "verbal parentheses" is affected by their length would answer?

Comment: So anyway, as far as I can tell the "verbal parenthesis" you are asking about is what German linguists call the "Mittelfeld" between the two ends of the "Satzklammer", see, e.g., http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/index.html?MenuId=Sentence531 . [continued]

Comment: [cont'd] One could then ask, has anyone researched whether comprehension of a text (to be measured by having subjects retell a text passage and the retelling evaluated by third parties) degrades linearly as the _Mittelfeld_ grows longer and more complex (naive assumption) or does it drop off exponentially or, conversely, decline asymptotically. If this is not what you're asking then please give more detail.

Comment: the only thing I know for fact is Kants Mittelfeld is too long for me.

Comment: @Emanuel LOL Kant is a model of clarity compared to Hegel.

Comment: This question needs further clarification on the meaning of [*"verbal parenthesis"*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parenthesis_%28rhetoric%29) which is by no means peculiar to German (in fact you use it in your question too). An example may help.

Comment: @indoxica: Do you mean a "Schachtelsatz" and its practical limit?

Comment: -1 to the question, for (1) ignoring my requests for clarification (2) asking an unclear question -- "to the un[c]onjugated form of the verb"?? (3) being unspecific to the German language -- Faulkner wrote sentences just as long and convoluted as Mann's (4) apparently asking for nothing more than common sense (longer and more complex sentences are harder to understand than shorter and simpler ones). Well D'Oh!!

Comment: @EugeneSeidel It is not about long and convoluted sentences, the question is about verbal parentheses, which I think means that the infinite part of the verbal phrase stands near the beginning of a sentence, while the finite part only comes at the end like in the Mann example below. Of course this is possible in other languages, as well, but it is something which German is notorious for. ("Ich habe, nachdem ich blablabla, während ich blablabla, das blablabla, einen Kaffee getrunken.")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no technical limit but just as in English, shortening your sentences can often make your writing simpler to understand.

Slightly related, [Thomas Mann](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Mann) was a German author with a penchant for crafting extravagantly long sentences.

EDIT:

There's a term for such ridiculous sentences: Schachtelsatz.

One from Thomas Mann:

> Der Autor der klaren und mächtigen Prosa-Epopöe vom Leben Friedrichs
>   von Preußen; der geduldige Künstler, der in langem Fleiß den
>   figurenreichen, so vielerlei Menschenschicksal im Schatten einer Idee
>   versammelnden Romanteppich, »Maja« mit Namen, wob; der Schöpfer
>   jener starken Erzählung, die »Ein Elender« überschrieben ist und einer
>   ganzen dankbaren Jugend die Möglichkeit sittlicher Entschlossenheit
>   jenseits der tiefsten Erkenntnis zeigte; der Verfasser endlich (und
>   damit sind die Werke seiner Reifezeit kurz bezeichnet) der
>   leidenschaftlichen Abhandlung über »Geist und Kunst«, deren
>   ordnende Kraft und antithetische Beredsamkeit ernste Beurteiler
>   vermochte, sie unmittelbar neben Schillers Raisonnement über naive
>   und sentimentalische Dichtung zu stellen: Gustav Aschenbach also war
>   zu L., einer Kreisstadt der Provinz Schlesien, als Sohn eines höheren
>   Justizbeamten geboren."

And here's an ironic example:

> "Ein Schachtelsatz ist eine über die notwendigen Satzteile – Subjekt, wie beispielsweise Pronomen, Substantive oder Numerale, Prädikat – als da wären Partizip II, Infinitiv bzw. Verbzusatz – und Objekt wie Genitiv-, Dativ-, Akkusativ- und Präpositionalobjekt, sowie die Adverbiale, Lokal-, Temporal- usw. -adverbiale und das Satzgliedteil Attribut – hinausgehend aus vielen ineinander verschachtelten, also immer wieder mit Einschüben, erklärenden oder ergänzenden; auch einfach erzählende – der Bildungsbürger sagt an dieser Stelle gern narrative – sind möglich, versehenen, Haupt- und Nebensätzen bestehende Satzkonstruktion [ist], die üblicherweise durch das Komma, das gängigste Satzzeichen zur Trennung der verschiedenen Satzglieder, welches komplizierten und mittlerweile dank der Rechtschreibreform (angeblich!) vereinfachten Regeln folgt, von vielen dennoch nicht korrekt angewendet wird oder werden kann – siehe PISA-Studie – oder auch den Gedankenstrich, welcher heute zwar eher unüblich ist, jedoch für erklärende Einschübe hin und wieder Verwendung findet, da er nicht nur eine Denkpause – wie diese hier – kenntlich machen kann, sondern auch etwas Abwechslung in einen Satz mit vielen Kommata – oder auch Kommas, beides ist korrekt – bringt und Parenthesen, also grammatisch selbstständige Einschübe, die den Sinnzusammenhang des Satzes unterbrechen, kennzeichnet, oder das ebenfalls weniger übliche Semikolon, zu Deutsch auch Strichpunkt genannt, als dessen inoffizieller Großmeister Thomas Mann, deutscher Schriftsteller des 20. Jahrhunderts und mit seinem Werk »Wo ich bin, ist Deutschland« geistiger Vater der Kampagne »Du bist Deutschland«, welcher in seinem »Zauberberg« bereits im zweiten Satz das erste und im dritten das zweite Semikolon setzte, gelten kann, getrennt werden und durch die möglicherweise verwirrende Komplexität als gesprochener Satz weniger in Frage kommt, da dem Sprecher, und sei er noch so eloquent, der Anfang seines Satzes schon längst entfallen sein könnte, noch bevor er über die Hälfte hinaus gekommen ist und seinen Gedanken zu Ende gesponnen hat, und allein aus diesem Grunde eher schriftlich formuliert wird, in der zeitgenössischen Literatur jedoch tendenziell an Länge einbüßt, sodass man heutzutage zu Recht Shakespeare's Lord Polonius mit "Brevity is the soul of wit" zitieren darf."

Comment: That is very interesting. Would you mind putting in your answer an example of such an _extravagantly long_ sentence? Curiosity is killing me...

Comment: The technical term would be hypotaxis or Hypotaxe in German. Your example of Mann shows his mastership of the genre, e.g. when he picks up the red line of the sentence just before he finishes it in order to make it readable. In his "Doctor Faustus" he also uses it in an ironic way when opening with a single sentence going on forever and not being able to finish it. The mock narrator then asks the reader's permission to start anew. So you see, there are limits.

Comment: @BoB Thank you for the quotations. That's a lot to read :)

Comment: ...also wer die zwei Beispielsätze oben zu Ende gelesen hat, darf sich jetzt selber upvoten...

Comment: Anstelle seines ersten Satzes hätte Th. Mann auch schreiben können "Dieses Buch ist nur für Bildungsbürger!" ;) Als Gegenbeispiel führe ich den (noch längeren) [ersten Satz von Thomas Bernhards Roman "Der Keller"](http://lesekreis.org/2007/07/11/der-schoenste-erste-satz-von-thomas-bernhard-11/) an, den auch ein Mensch mit Volksschulbildung genießen kann.

Answer (score 3):

The longer the sentence, the greater the chances that the reader will have forgotten the beginning of the sentence and the auxiliary verb by the time they reach the end. Thus there surely is a practical limit.

But where that limit lies depends very much on a large number of factors. When you can guess the meaning of the main verb from the context, waiting for it is a lot easier than when you have no clue. When the parts inside the parenthesis require a lot of thought (e.g. in scientific texts), they will be more likely to distract you from the main sentence than when they are lengthy but simple in structure (e.g. containing an enumeration of similar things). Nesting level is of course another factor: the deeper you nest your sentences one inside the other, the more difficult to parse the whole construct will become.